# node promise is not executing synchronously

Tags: node.js, promise

I am trying to use node promises to create a sequence that is called synchronously so that a result is available to be returned to the caller.

My code is as shown below.

```
console.log("Call Outer HubTest");
var outerConnection;
var ret = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    port     : '3306',
    user     : 'MyUser',
    password : 'MyPwd',
    database : 'MyDb'
}).then(function (conn) {
    console.log("OuterhubTest: Set Connection to "+conn);
    outerConnection = conn; 
}).then(function (result) {
    console.log("OuterhubTest: Connection is"+outerConnection);
    return outerConnection.query("SELECT 1");
}).then(function (rows) {
    console.log("OuterhubTest: Rows of length "+rows.length);
}).catch(function (err) { console.log("Error was "+err)})
console.log("After OuterhubTest");
```

The trace I observe implies that the chain is being invoked asynchronously:-

```
Call Outer HubTest
After OuterhubTest
OuterhubTest: Set Connection to [object Object]
OuterhubTest: Connection is[object Object]
OuterhubTest: Rows of length 1
```

If this was synchronous, I would have expected all OuterhubTest trace to have been before "After OuterhubTest". I am not sure what I am doing wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Promises don't make asynchronous code synchronous.

Comment: Promises are inherently asynchonous.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are not magic. They don't do anything outside of what is possible with regular JavaScript.

Promises only synchronize what's *inside* a promise chain as you see in your example. In fact - promises guarantee that in this scenario:

```
log(1);
promise.then(() => log(2));
log(3);
```

The order will always be `1,3,2` - and this is in order to avoid [Zalgo](http://blog.izs.me/post/59142742143/designing-apis-for-asynchrony).